# Ajax request not working from validation.js

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, prototype-js

I have added one ajax validation for a custom section in magento checkout page as below,

Validation.js :

```
['validate-otp', 'Please enter valid OTP.', function(v) {
        var url = 'customsect/processing/test?code='+v;
        new Ajax.Request(url, {
            method: 'get',
            onSuccess: function(response){
                alert(response.responseJSON);
            },
            onComplete: function(res){
                alert("complete");
            },
            onFailure: function(err){
                alert("Error"+err);
            }
        });
     }]
```

app/code/local/myaddon/customsect/controllers/ProcessingController.php :

```
public function testAction()
    {
        $code = $this->getRequest()->getParams('code');
        $itemArr = array('res' => $code);
        // $data = json_encode($itemArr);
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type','application/json');       $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($itemArr));
    }
```

But am getting alert as "null". When i run below url I'm getting the json response displayed.

http://127.0.0.1/mage3/index.php/customsect/processing/test?code=ADXWZ

```
{"res":{"code":"ADXWZ"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update code

```
['validate-otp', 'Please enter valid OTP.', function(v) {
        var url = 'http://127.0.0.1/mage3/index.php/customsect/processing/test?code='+v;
        new Ajax.Request(url, {
            method: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            onSuccess: function(response){
                alert(response);
            },
            onFailure: function(err){
                alert("Error"+err);
            }
        });
     }]
```

Comment: I tried this. But getting an empty alert first then "complete" alert.

Comment: I have updated code please try with this

Comment: I removed the dataType json and then used "echo" in controller side. Now getting the response as "response.responseText".

Answer (score 1):

Your Ajax request url should dynamic.

Define *a java script which is content request url val* at head.phtml

***`var OtpUrl="<?php echo $this->getUrl('RouteId/process/test')?>";`***

and *call this variable instead of variable  url* at  `validation.js`

Change `new Ajax.Request(url, {` to `new Ajax.Request(OtpUrl, {`

**And send parameter list**

```
 parameters: {code: v}
```

Code may like:

```
new Ajax.Request(OtpUrl,
{
 method:'get',
 parameters: {code: v},
 requestHeaders: {  Accept: 'application/json'   },
        onSuccess: function(transport) {
            var response = transport.responseText.evalJSON(true);
        },
     onFailure: function(){ alert('Something went wrong...') }
});
```

Comment: Php tag will work in .js file?

Comment: no, It need to define at phtml or php file and i have update it

Comment: I am getting [object object] when alerting the response.but unable to fetch the exact value of response.

Comment: use `alert(response.res )`

Comment: It's a blank alert.

Comment: please check first  `OtpUrl` give request url